# R, Plyr, Error using ddply on function with different length output / rbind.fill

Tags: r, subset, plyr

I have an error that I don't know how to resolve in the following code using ddply :

```
FLF.DJ = ddply(dat, c("Trial.group","Location"), function(sub_dat) { 

ST_sow = ST_sowing[ST_sowing$Trial.group %in% unique(sub_dat$Trial.group) &
ST_sowing$Location %in% unique(sub_dat$Location),]   
do.call(rbind, lapply(sub_dat[, "X0142_FLF"], function(x) {
get.DJ(ST_sow[-c(1:3)], as.Date(x, origin="2013-06-01"))}))

})
```

Error

```
Error in output[rng, lcols[[i]]] <- matrices[[i]] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

With:

```
get.DJ = function(df,date){
ST=df[ ,which(as.Date(colnames(df)) == date)]
return(c(ST))
}
```

If i only run the center part of the code of `function(sub_dat){...}` it works well, but I can't get it to work with the ddply part to apply the function to each subset ( by `"Trial.group","Location"`) of my data.

Any suggestion? 
Thanks for your help !

EDIT :
I think that the problem comes from the length of the returned dataframes of the function in `ddply`. 
`ddply` use a  `rbind.fill` to combine all output data, but their length differs and that's causing the error. do you have a suggestion ? 
I tried to use a loop instead with rbind, but with the same kind of error :

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length')
```

Comment: You're assuming that `ST_sow` will always have at least 4 elements. Have you verified this still remains true after breaking your data into groups?

Comment: there was a missing coma in `ST_sow[,-c(1:3)]` but this is not the problem `ST_sow` always more that 3 columns.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the different length of the output data from the function...